# Shared Repositories Among Separate Git Projects (Repositories)

Tags: git, version-control, branch

I have seen many similar Q&A so I'll apologize up-front for what might seem like a duplicate question.  But I have read through all of what I could find (here and on the web in general) and I still do not have an answer.

We currently use SVN (Tortoise and Ankh are the tools) as our VCS and are considering a move to Git.  Our interest is in gaining better capabilities where branching is concerned.  Simplistically, our projects are like this:

```
Project1
Project2
SharedCode
```

Each of these two projects relies intimately upon the SharedCode (in fact, they are inseparable).  Therefore, if I am working on Project1, I need to be able to checkout a repository that is comprised of Project1 and SharedCode (always).  Likewise for Project2, it must be comprised of both Project2 and SharedCode.

As the name suggests, SharedCode is a collection of shared libraries, shared projects, and reference files.  Each project equates to a Solution in Visual Studio speak.  That means that each is actually a collection of VC# code projects.  The tie is that these individual VC# projects will have references to things in SharedCode, such as reference DLLs, or even other VC# code projects that exist in the SharedCode directory.

What I really want to stress is that the structure is the most important part of my issue.  I cannot use a method that makes the "linked" code (i.e. the SharedCode) a specific commit.  It must always be the HEAD (the very latest published code), just as Project 1 or 2 would be.

Now, I understand that I could simply make each a separate repository and check them each out individually.  But what happens when I want to branch?  Here is an example of a potentially dangerous situation:

I have branched Project1 and SharedCode, and I have each checked out.  I also have Project2 checked out, but it is not branched.  I begin work on something in Project2, but because Project2 uses code pages from SharedCode, I could be working on a hybrid of an un-branched Project2 and a branched SharedCode.

So, in summary, I want to be able to checkout Project1 and SharedCode, or Project2 and SharedCode, always in those pairs.  Conversely, I must also be able to commit changes together so that all code remains aligned.

What are my options?  Have you any similar needs, or experience in how to handle this scenario and avoid the dangerous situations?

I thank you in advance for assistance with structuring our new Git repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to provide an end to the story, so to speak, here is what we ended up doing.  Instead of attempting a structure in which we have a shared repository, we have elected to create a single large repository that includes Project1, Project2, and SharedCode altogether.  This will mean more stuff getting copied around and being included in branches/tags, but ultimately it best facilitates ensuring that each project always has the SharedCode it needs.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should have a look at

`man githook` ([online manpage](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/githooks.html))

with githooks you can define scripts starting after pull, or push, so you can pull and push the SharedCode, too. I don't really know what is possible at all, but maybe this will help you a little bit.

Comment: I agree that this could help automate some of the "get it all together" and "push it all together" processes.  However, it would not help to address the main concern, which is ensuring that the project working copies do not get into the dangerous hybrid states.

Comment: ok, i'm Not shure understanding you. Do you want that all pushes of shared are pushed to master, even if the project pushes to a branch and All pulls are pulling from shared master, so that the Projects always working with head of shared?

Comment: No.  Please refer back to my example scenario, whereby Project1 and SharedCode are branched but Project2 is not.  Physically, when I open Project2 code, and I see there a file that is referenced from the SharedCode directory, I am thus in the "hybrid" state.  I am working in what I _think_ is a HEAD Project2, but in reality I am modifying a SharedCode file that is from a branch.  It will not be readily clear when I have entered this dangerous state, and therefore, possible that unintended changes get committed across HEAD/branch lines.